# How does code injection affect stack in this case

Tags: assembly

So I was attempting to inject code in attack lab assignment and for phase 1 all that was required was to give any input to fill the character array buffer exactly and then following it the address of the "touch1" function.

For example, if the buffer had a size of 0x10 bytes (not the one I got), then I would write something like:

00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 (padding)

<< insert address of touch1

This works as expected, but the problem is in phase 2, where I have to inject a code to move cookie to %rdi and then touch2, I don't know why an injection like this works:

<code injection to move cookie to %rdi> /* 8 bytes */

00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 (padding)

<< insert address of touch2

This code has 8 extra bytes then touch1, but the buffer size is still the same, and this confuses me because touch2's address replaces things even higher up in the stack than the return address.

It appears that the only way I can understand this is if returning from a function increments the stack pointer by 8 bytes so after running the injected code, the rip reaches the address of touch2, but then wouldn't touch2's address replace some other possibly important code and could cause undefined behaviour?

Comment: Does it actually work? Do you have a real executable with real code to test? If the first input actually overwrites the return address, so must do the second input, but *with zero*.

Comment: Yea it does work because when I ran the 2nd code it cleared phase 2 of the assignment

Comment: But you don't have the vulnerable binary or code, right?

Comment: Yea, I don't have that

Comment: So, it's probably a faked result.